# Drop variables using non-missing values as criterion

Tags: for-loop, foreach, stata

I'm working with long data; I have about 100 variables, with a lot of missing values. I want to loop through the variables and delete variables with less than "some number", e.g., 32, of non-missing values.

I tried the following:

```
foreach var of varlist cid-lpop {
  2. bysort `var': drop if _N < 32
  3. }
```

but it dropped all of my observations.

(This question is cross-listed on Statalist under the same title).

Comment: Answered on Statalist as well, see https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1408083-drop-columns-using-non-missing-observations-as-criteria

Comment: Strictly, it's the values that are or are not missing, not the observations. Many would be happy to call an observation missing if all its values were missing, but in general an observation could easily have some missing and some non-missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joseph Coveney at Statalist provided the following solution:

```
foreach var of varlist cid-lpop {
    count if !missing(`var')
    if r(N) < 32 drop `var'
}
```